# How to relate APScheduler JobStore with SQLAlchemy Models (foreign key) - Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I've got a Python Flask app using `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` and `apscheduler.schedulers.background`. I've created a JobStore and gotten a table called `apscheduler_jobs` is has the following fields:

```
|id  |next_run_time|job_state|
------------------------------
|TEXT|   REAL      |  TEXT   |
```

I want to relate a an SQLAlchemy Model object to that table using something like this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy', url=app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])

class Event(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "event"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    jobs = db.relationship('scheduler', backref='apscheduler_jobs')
```

So I want to use the table from the APScheduler apscheduler_jobs and then associate that with a foreign key to my Event object. That last line there will basically break as "scheduler" isn't a defined SQLAlchmey model

```
qlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Event|event, expression 'scheduler' failed to locate a name ("name 'scheduler' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'project.models.Event'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

So I think I need an inbetween Model class called "job" or something, then relate that to apscheduler_jobs, but something here still feels bad - because APScheduler is making this table up I've got no control over what's going on there - should I be concerned about that?

**EDIT1:**
So I created 2 models, one "Event" then one "Job", the "Job" then relates to the table `apscheduler_jobs`

```
class Job(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "job"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    apscheduler_job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('apscheduler_jobs.id'))
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
```

problem there is that when I dropped the DB and recreated it it's thrown the error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'job.apscheduler_job_id' could not find table 'apscheduler_jobs' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

Now I could get around that in my database creation script, but again it still feels like I'm doing this the wrong way

**EDIT2**
I managed to get it to work, though this feels pretty wrong, I've now got 3 models: Event, Job, and APSchedulerJobsTable. The final model basically matches what the APScheduler apscheduler_jobs looks like. There must be a better way to do this though.

```
from project import db


class Event(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "event"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    jobs = db.relationship('Job', backref='job_event')


class Job(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "job"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    apscheduler_job_id = db.Column(db.TEXT, db.ForeignKey('apscheduler_jobs.id'))
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))


class APSchedulerJobsTable(db.Model):
    # TODO: This feels bad man
    __tablename__ = "apscheduler_jobs"

    id = db.Column(db.TEXT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    next_run_time = db.Column(db.REAL)
    job_state = db.Column(db.TEXT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, two solutions - neither really perfect IMO:

**Solution One**, probably more clean - simply have a Text field in the job table that contains aspscheduler_job_ids - this is not a foreign key though but once the aspscheduler_job ID is known it's possible to go ahead and store it in the job table for later reference

```
class Event(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "event"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    jobs = db.relationship('Job', backref='job_event')


class Job(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "job"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
    apscheduler_job_id = db.Column(db.TEXT)
```

Catch for this one is in order to drop the full db you'll need to run this to include dropping the unmanaged table `apscheduler_jobs`:

```
db.reflect()
db.drop_all()
```

**Solution Two**, add the apscheduler table to the model itself, and then set up the foreign key:

```
class Event(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "event"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    jobs = db.relationship('Job', backref='job_event')


class Job(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "job"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
    apscheduler_job_id = db.Column(db.TEXT, db.ForeignKey('apscheduler_jobs.id'))


class APSchedulerJobsTable(db.Model):
    # TODO: This feels bad man
    __tablename__ = "apscheduler_jobs"

    id = db.Column(db.TEXT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    next_run_time = db.Column(db.REAL)
    job_state = db.Column(db.TEXT)
    job = db.relationship('Job', backref='job_event')
```